# How to get separated auth for admin and user models in Adonis JS

Tags: adonis.js, adonisjs-ace

Is it possible to have **separated Auth for different models in Adonis Js**?

I have two different table for admins and users and **want to have separated Auth**.

How can I setup this in adonis js ?

Comment: Adonis v4 or v5?

Comment: Do you want to use other tables than adonisjs give?

Comment: Version is : Adonis V5

Comment: Yes absolutely @Amit

Answer (score 2):

You can configure multiple authentication by adding new auth in your `config/auth.ts` in `guards` section.

### Example

#### `config/auth.ts` :

```js
const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  guard: 'api_users',
  guards: {
    // User API token authentication
    api_users: {
      driver: 'oat',
      tokenProvider: {
        driver: 'database',
        table: 'user_api_tokens' // API token table - don't forget to create migration
      },
      provider: {
        driver: 'lucid',
        identifierKey: 'id',
        uids: ['name'],
        model: () => import('App/Models/User')
      }
    },
    // Client API token authentication
    api_clients: {
      driver: 'oat',
      tokenProvider: {
        driver: 'database',
        table: 'client_api_tokens' // API token table - don't forget to create migration
      },
      provider: {
        driver: 'lucid',
        identifierKey: 'id',
        uids: ['email'],
        model: () => import('App/Models/Client')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Switch authentication :

```js
public async myCustomControllerFunction ({ auth, response }: HttpContextContract, next: () => Promise<void>) {
    const clientAuth = auth.use('api_clients')
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not working. When I add a new guard named admin it gives an error to add in guard list. You can try this on new web scaffolding of Adonis 5. Got error on driver i.e lucid or basic

Comment: Did you install lucid provider? Can you share the full error?

Comment: Yes I have installed Lucid. I am giving you full error. Your answer is for API scaffolding. I am using web scaffolding. You can try new version of web scaffolding.

Comment: One more thing Do I need to use custom User provider to achieve this ??

Comment: Doesn't work, seems like typescript screams at you

Answer (score 0):

You can create new guards or providers by register them inside the contracts/auth.ts file to inform the TypeScript static compiler.

https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/introduction#configuring-new-guardsproviders

Example:

```
  .....
  interface GuardsList {
    .....
    apiUsers: {
      implementation: OATGuardContract<'user', 'apiUsers'>,
      config: OATGuardConfig<'user'>,
    }
    .....
  }
  .....
```

Comment: Can you provide the detailed process of how a seperate admin panel can be setup in adonis 5 using AdminUser Model ?